# XSL version 1.0- Absolute Value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL and looking for help on returning an absolute value for the following:

```
xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number(@firstOffset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
```

I know someone has posted `$vNum*($vNum >=0) - $vNum*($vNum &lt; 0)` but I cant get it to work, any help?

Do I substitute all the `inr:distanceFormat(number(@firstOffset), $xslDistancePrecision)` for `Num` in the absolute formula?

Thanks
Drumdivan

Answer (score 1):

Simplest (not necessarily fastest) is probably just to strip any minus sign from the string representation: `number(translate(string(xxx), '-', ''))`

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="vNum" select="inr:distanceFormat(number(@firstOffset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
```

then use the suggestion `<xsl:value-of select="$vNum*($vNum >=0) - $vNum*($vNum &lt; 0)"/>`.